# Prove that $(1+2+3+\cdots+n)^2=1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation

Prove that $(1+2+3+\cdots+n)^2=1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to use induction on this one, but I'm not sure how to. The base case is clearly true. But when I add $n+1$ to the right and left hand sides, I don't know what I'm supposed to get. For example, when I extend the right hand side's sequence by $n+1$, I get $n^3+(n+1)^3$ at the end of the sequence, which is $2n^3 +3n^2+3n+1$.

This doesn't seem that meaningful, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Integrator Use "flag" and put the URL of the previous.

Comment: @Integrator That's not the same identity ...

Comment: @Zubin Yes it is, since $1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$.

Comment: It's enough of a rearrangement to justify another question, yes?

Comment: @Zubin It's a straight composition of two mathematical facts which can already be found on MSE. If all these merited separate question, there would be way too much noise.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Some theorems directly follow from definitions. Perhaps we should just not write out the theorems because they're "too much noise"?

Comment: @Integrator Could you link to it in a comment so it shows up in "Linked"?

Comment: @Integrator Okay, then it'd make sense to link those instead of the one you did ... perhaps I'm being pedantic

Comment: @Zubin I think it's bad form to link a duplicate to another duplicate

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Not at all, if the duplicate has answers of its own. If A points to B and C points to B, the content of A remains unnoticed. If C points to A instead, all three are easily accessible.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Actually, the contents of all duplicates are available from the "hub" question which links to these in the "linked" sidebar, but ideally all answers should be focused on the hub question so one doesn't have to run around to find a good answer. (FYI there are at least four exact duplicates of this question which can be found this way.)

Answer (score 0):

When you extend the right side you don't get $n+(n+1)^3$, you get $\sum_{i=1}^ni^3+(n+1)^3$  In the original question it was $n$, but in the edit it was $n^3$.  Both are incorrect.

Comment: I assumed he was just writing about the last two terms, which are $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$; the reason I edited it is because he said whatever he was talking about was equal to $2n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$, which is only true if he was talking about $n^3 + (n+1)^3$ and not $n+(n+1)^3$. Also, shouldn't you have made that a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @Integrator:  I thought this would be useful to OP to see where the problem was.  I was the second close vote.

Comment: @Integrator It is *not* a duplicate of the question you linked. That is a different identity.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee:  it looks the same to me, once you make the left side inside the parentheses the triangular number.

Comment: @RossMillikan Is $20/2 = 10$ the same identity as $5+5=20/2$? Seems like quibbling over words ... EDIT: maybe a better example is the well-ordering principle and mathematical induction, which are equivalent but shouldn't be called the same thing

Comment: @Integrator You seem very particular about certain rules of the site, but you just upvoted an answer that was not an answer and should be a comment.